# Google Cloud AutoML prediction on Docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-automl

I've trained a multi-class object detection model on Google Cloud AutoML. I've dowloaded my own model from *Container* export. Than I've deployed it on Docker with Google Cloud AutoML docker image. And I've send request with this code:

```
import base64
import io
import json
import requests


def process(image_file_path, image_key="1", port_number=8501):
    with io.open(image_file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')

    instances = {
            "instances": [
                    {
                        "image_bytes": {
                            "b64": str(encoded_image)
                        },
                        "key": image_key
                    }
            ]
    }

    url = 'http://localhost:{}/v1/models/default:predict'.format(port_number)

    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(instances))
    return response.json()
```

I've successfully get the response from the docker as json format:

```
{
    "predictions": [{
        "detection_multiclass_scores": [
            [0.00540795922, 0.99754715], 
            ...
        ],
        "detection_classes": [1.0, ...],
        "num_detections": 40.0,
        "image_info": [320, 320, 1, 0, 320, 320],
        "detection_boxes": [
            [0.0382162929, 0.0984618068, 0.746192276, 0.991413414], 
            ...
        ],
        "detection_scores": [0.99754715, ...],
        "detection_classes_as_text": ["image_class", ...],
        "key": "1"
    }]
}
```

At this point, I want to know where is the detected bounding box in the image. I know that I should get this information with `detection_boxes`, but I need to convert it to px values. Because I'll process the bounding boxes again.

What is the pattern of the `detection_boxes`?

Comment: it is %. if your image have 1280 width just multipy for the number ex: `1280*0.0382162929`

Comment: I know that. I'm asking what is the pattern like x1,y1,x2,y2

Answer (score 2):

The format of detection_boxes is
`[min_y, min_x, max_y, max_x]`, these values are normalized by the height and width of the image, so to get pixel coordinates `y*height` and `x*width`.

This is the same format as used by the Tensorflow Object Detection API, you can read about the format [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md)